# Выборка в sql запросе

Tags: php, mysql, sql

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В столбце users перечислены id некоторых пользователей. Они могут быть в разном порядке и в любой иерархии. Подскажите пожалуйста запрос к столбцу users если заранее известно только, что придется искать от 2-х пользователей и более.

Пример 1: нужно найти есть ли ячейках пользователи 2 и 3

Пример 2: нужно найти есть ли ячейках пользователи 150, 3, 56

Comment: Учи SQL и НИКОГДА не храни в БД значения разделенные запятыми. Вместо этого нужно сделать еще одну таблицу и записывать эти значения каждое в свою строчку

Comment: Ответов на подобные вопросы море. Но переделать таблицу действительно надо, SQL в принципе не предназначен для работы со списками через запятую. Такая работа - только полным перебором таблицы, что долго

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[find_in_set](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set)

никакие регекспы и лайки тут не нужны.
@Ипатьев, скорее прав, чем нет, хотя чересчур категоричен на тему "никогда".

```
mysql> use temp;
Reading table information for completion of table and column names
You can turn off this feature to get a quicker startup with -A

Database changed
mysql> create table a(id int, t text);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)

mysql> insert into a values (0, '1,2,3');
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from a where find_in_set(1,t);
+------+-------+
| id   | t     |
+------+-------+
|    0 | 1,2,3 |
+------+-------+
1 row in set (0.02 sec)

mysql> select * from a where find_in_set(5,t);
Empty set (0.00 sec)
```

если есть индекс на t, и t не слишком длинный (varchar, например) то вполне быстро будет работать.  like и regexp тут и неправильны и громадные потери по производительности

Comment: Спасибо. Это мне подходит. Только вот мне необходимо будет искать 2 и более числа за раз. Если необходимо найти числа 2 и 3 то код будет такой: select * from a where find_in_set(2,t) and find_in_set(3,t); Если искать 3 числа, то запрос еще удлиняется. Нельзя ли его как нибудь сократить??

Comment: если чисел не очень много, то подобное увеличение запроса скриптом не окажет заметного влияния на производительность, если оочень много - надо рефакторить схему (отдельная таблица и т.д.)

Answer (score 0):

Если необходимо узнать только факт наличия необходимых id пользователей в столбце users, то можно воспользоваться LIKE:

Пример 1:

```
SELECT id FROM table WHERE users LIKE('%2%3%');
```

или

```
SELECT id FROM table WHERE users LIKE('%2%') AND users LIKE('%3%');
```

Но изменить структуру БД в любом случае стоит.

Comment: Ваш запрос выведет ошибочные значения, т.е. все значения где есть двойка или тройка, даже если это будет 123 232 652531. Тут нужен REGEXP, а не LIKE.